# Let $E=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. What is the normal closure of $E/E$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $E=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. What is the normal closure of $E/E$?

My thought is the $A(2^{1/3})$ where $A$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. But I am not sure whether it is correct and why...
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you know how the normal closure is defined and/or some characterizations of it? The answer is not correct. The correct answer is $Q (2^{1/3}, \zeta_3)$ where $\zeta_3$ is a third root of unity. But without further details it is hard to write a detailed answer that will be useful to you.

Comment: I feel that is the normal closure of E/Q. If the ground field is E already, we don't need to care about the minimal polynomial of 2^1/3, right?

Comment: Sorry, I glossed over that, indeed my answer is for E/Q. This is almost a trick question, then. The normal closure of a field over itself is always the field itself as every field is normal over itself. So if you really want to ask for E/E the answer is E.

Comment: Thank you. But I still feel strange. Like f=x^2-2 in E[x] but f does not split in E? So we need a normal closure for Q then plus 2^1/3?

Answer (score 2):

The field $\;A(\sqrt[3]2)\;$, with $\;A=\overline{\Bbb Q}\;$ is way, way too big for being the normal closure of the given field. You only need to "enlarge" the given field the exact amount in order to make the extension "normal" without losing algebraicity.

Now, putting $\;\alpha:=\sqrt[3]2\;$, we see the minimal polynomial of this element over the rationals is $\;x^3-2\;$ , and since all the roots of this pol. are  $\;\alpha,\,\alpha w,\,\alpha w^2\;,\;\;w:=e^{2\pi i/3}\;$,  the extension $\;\Bbb Q(\alpha,w)/\Bbb Q\;$ already contains $\;\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q\;$ and it is already normal as it is **the** splitting field of $\;x^3-2\;$ over $\;\Bbb Q\;$.

Thus, you've already found your normal closure: it is $\;\Bbb Q(\alpha,w)/\Bbb Q\;$ .

Comment: . The question asked for $E/E$ not $E/Q$ and it was confirmed in comments this was the actual intent.

Comment: First, not always I do read the comments but rather the question...and someting not even that but only the header. My bad, indeed...yet: second,  if the question **really** is what is the normal closure of $\;E/E\;$ then it is an almost absurdly trivial and boring question. I'm not sure I would have addressed this even if I had read the question correctly.

Comment: Actually, it is in the header.

Answer (score 1):

The normal closure of $E/E$ is $E$.

Note that a normal closure of a finite extension is always a finite extension, excluding your answer. Also note that $A[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is in fact equal to $A$.

[Recall that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension) a characterization of normal is: "Every irreducible polynomial in K[X] that has one root in L, has all of its roots in L, that is, it decomposes into linear factors in L[X]."

Yet the only way that a polynomial $f$ in $E[X]$ that is *irreducible* can have a root in $E$ is that it is of degree $1$.

Note that the polynomial $x^3 -2$ is not irreducible over $E$. *Therefore* it is no longer a problem that it does not decompose.

Or, for example the polynomial $x^2 - 2$ has **no** root in $E$, so it is not relevant it does not decompose.